# Apache Airflow - use python result in the next steps

Tags: airflow

I am working on some simple Apache Airflow DAG. My goal is to:
1. calculate the data parameter based on the DAG run date - I try achieve that by the Python operator.
2. pass the parameter calculated above as a bq query parameter.

Any ideas are welcom.

My code below - I have marked the two points with I am struggling with by the 'TODO' label.

```
...

def set_date_param(dag_run_time):
    # a business logic applied here
    ....

    return "2020-05-28" # example result

# --------------------------------------------------------
# DAG definition below
# --------------------------------------------------------

# Python operator
set_data_param = PythonOperator(
  task_id='set_data_param',
  python_callable=set_data_param,
  provide_cotext=True,
  op_kwargs={
    "dag_run_date": #TODO - how to pass the DAG running date as a function input parameter
  },
  dag=dag
)

# bq operator
load_data_to_bq_table = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='load_data_to_bq_table',
    sql="""SELECT ccustomer_id, sales
    FROM `my_project.dataset1.table1` 
    WHERE date_key = {date_key_param}
    """.format(
       date_key_param = 
   ), #TODO - how to get the python operator results from the previous step
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    destination_dataset_table="my_project.dataset2.table2}",
    trigger_rule='all_success',
    dag=dag
)

set_data_param >> load_data_to_bq_table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For `PythonOperator` to pass the execution date to the `python_callable`, you only need to set `provide_cotext=True` (as it has been already done in your example). This way, [Airflow automatically passes a collection of keyword arguments](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/python.html#templating) to the python callable, such that the names and values of these arguments are equivalent to the template variables described [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros-ref.html). That is, if you define the python callable as `set_data_param(ds, **kwargs): ...`, the `ds` parameter will automatically get the execution date as a string value in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.
2. [XCOM](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms) allows task instances to exchange messages. To use the date returned by `set_date_param()` inside the `sql` query string of `BigQueryOperator`, you can combine XCOM with [Jinja templating](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#jinja-templating):

```
sql="""SELECT ccustomer_id, sales
    FROM `my_project.dataset1.table1` 
    WHERE date_key = {{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='set_data_param') }}
    """
```

The following complete example puts all pieces together. In the example, the `get_date` task creates a date string based on the execution date. After that, the `use_date` task uses XCOM and Jinja templating to retrieve the date string and writes it to a log.

```
import logging
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {'start_date': days_ago(1)}


def calculate_date(ds, execution_date, **kwargs):
    return f'{ds} ({execution_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")})'


def log_date(date_string):
    logging.info(date_string)


with DAG(
    'a_dag',
    schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *',
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    get_date = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get_date',
        python_callable=calculate_date,
        provide_context=True,
    )
    use_date = PythonOperator(
        task_id='use_date',
        python_callable=log_date,
        op_args=['Date: {{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids="get_date") }}'],
    )
get_date >> use_date
```

Comment: Hi, after application the code into bq I get somethig like below when run: `WHERE date_key = { task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='set_date_key_param') }` - any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @TomaszKubat It looks like you are applying `format()` to the query string that interprets curly braces on its own. If so, you have to escape the curly braces of the Jinja template: `{{{{ task_instance... }}}}`. If not, please ask a new question and provide a complete example of the code.

Comment: Hi, I have created another question/ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62132609/airflow-xcom-pull-in-the-bigquery-operator